# Using pretty URLs with react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to get the hang of react-router, but I can't seem to find a way to remove the /#/ from the URLs. My use-case is extremely simple, just two pages that I want to route between. Here are my routes:

```
var React = require('react'),
    Router = require('react-router'),
    Route = Router.Route,

    App = require('./app.jsx'),
    Home = require('./home.jsx'),
    Test = require('./test.jsx')

var routes = (
    <Route name="app" handler={App}>
        <Route name="home" path="/" handler={Home}/>
        <Route name="test" path="/test" handler={Test}/>
    </Route>
)

Router.run(routes, Router.HashLocation, function(Root){
    React.render(
        <Root />,
        document.body
    )
})
```

I've been using ui-router in the past with Angular, so I'm expecting there's a prop somewhere that I need to add, but I'm not sure.

This is a static site (hosted on GitHub), so I can't change the server as such. Since it used to work with ui-router, I'm sure there is a way to get this to work too.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [documentation on HistoryLocation](http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#HistoryLocation).

You'll need to configure your server to handle the requests accordingly too (so it knows to serve your routes, not a file saved to the server).

```
Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function (Root) {
   React.render( <Root/>,  document.body );
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't really configure the server though as I'm using GitHub.